# Temporarily disable particular css style from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a particularly specific question that there are many articles online but they don't answer my question.

I have a menu bar on my website where some `<li>` elements appear when the user is logged in. That `<li>` element also has an onhover dropdown styled in css with the following:

```
ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

So what happens is, when the `<li>` element of the main  (which has a direct child of `<ul>`) is hovered upon, the dropdown will appear. Pretty straightforward.

My problem is, when I hide that particular `<li>` element with the dropdown attached to it (through the following code within a javascript if statement), the hover style remains.

So even though the parent `<li>` is set to `display: none;`, the child  dropdown can be revealed by hovering over a tiny invisible rectangle (see picture) in the header.

[image: Screenshot of my hidden dropdown that I want removed]

**TLDR:** is there a way I can temporarily disable that particular `:hover` style preferrably through javascript or jQuery?

Thanks for the help in advance.

My HTML code for anyone wondering: (I have removed unncessary stuff so it is easier to see what I mean)

```
<ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li id="dropdown">
        <p class="drop" id="loggedInValue"></p>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="account.php">My Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php?logout=true">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just added my HTML code for anyone wondering

Comment: for how long do you want to disable the `:hover` effect? Could you share your entire html & css file?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal. I want to disable the `:hover` effect when the user is logged in. So it would be for any given period of time (depending upon user input). If you're wondering, it is not a time delay event.

Comment: I don't understand. An element with `display:none` will not receive hover events. Can you clarify or elaborate on the problem?

Comment: When you are setting li to display: none, you can add a class and add :not(class-name) to the css

Comment: @rayhatfield. Yes, I thought that would be the case, but that is not working here. Maybe someone can explain.

Comment: @rayhatfield. I just realised I don't need to do this. I just need to add an `!important` tag to the `display: none;` (default) style. Because for some reason, it is being overridden by a `display: inline-block;` style for the horizontal list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are setting li to display: none, you can add a class to li (class-name, for example) and add :not(class-name) to the css.
See below example for reference

```
ul li:not(.class-name):hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

P.S: I am wondering how is that little rectangle even visible, when you have set it to display: none. There is definitely some part left out when setting display to none

Comment: Yeah, I realised it's being overridden by another `display: inline-block;`. So I just added an `!important` tag on the `display: none;`. But I will leave this question just incase it is useful to someone else with a similar but slightly different problem.

Comment: Great. But !important is not one of the best practices. I hope you know that

Comment: I know. I actually had to end up using ray hatfield's solution because of a double !important thing that is too complicated to explain.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `logged-in` css class to the root html element, and predicate the hover selector on the presence of that class.

```js
const onLoginSuccess = () => {
  document.documentElement.classList.add('logged-in');
}
```

```css
.logged-in ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is a great method. I like your thinking. Let me have a go.

Answer (score 0):

If there should be no drop down then you should run some code similar to this.
Please let me know if this helped.
Have a good one.

```
const dropdown = document.querySelector('#dropdown');
dropdown.classList.remove('dropdown-styles');
```

Comment: maybe try '#dropdown:hover'

Comment: Is there a way you could share a code snippet or fiddle

Comment: I will try `#dropdown:hover` and see if it works. As if it does, it is a cleaner solution than Ray's. Although his still works fine.

Comment: Still didn't work for me. I think the problem is that you've said `dropdown.classList.remove('dropdown-styles`);`

But I don't have any classes on that element. I am simply using relative selection through css.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just completely delete the element from the DOM

```
const dropdown = document.querySelector('#dropdown');
dropdown.parentNode.removeChild(dropdown);
```